# Apache2 server not wotking

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-18.04

For some reason my apache2 has stopped working.
I have tried uninstalling it, the problem still remains the same. 
Here's some commands and their results that I have tried which might help you:-

**"sudo systemctl status apache2":-**

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-06-21 12:56:28 IST; 7min ag
     Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

Jun 21 12:56:21 kabir systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 21 12:56:28 kabir apachectl[1086]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably dete
Jun 21 12:56:28 kabir apachectl[1086]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make
Jun 21 12:56:28 kabir apachectl[1086]: no listening sockets available, shutting 
Jun 21 12:56:28 kabir apachectl[1086]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jun 21 12:56:28 kabir apachectl[1086]: Action 'start' failed.
Jun 21 12:56:28 kabir apachectl[1086]: The Apache error log may have more inform
Jun 21 12:56:28 kabir systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=
Jun 21 12:56:28 kabir systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code
Jun 21 12:56:28 kabir systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

**"sudo systemctl restart apache2":-**

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**netstat -an | grep ":80"**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:33944    117.18.237.29:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:33864    117.18.237.29:80        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:34524    23.217.53.84:80         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:54364    172.217.166.163:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:54206    172.217.166.163:80      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:33946    117.18.237.29:80        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:34522    23.217.53.84:80         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

**"sudo apachectl start":-**

```
Invoking 'systemctl start apache2'.
Use 'systemctl status apache2' for more info.
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: And if you run sudo systemctl apache2.service as the error suggests?

Comment: check in the question i did run that command

Comment: Sorry it is early, didn't really clarify. But from the error i would say you have multiple listen directives in your httpd.conf.

Comment: Yes. Actually I was trying to install kali tools and since then i am unable to start my apache

Comment: Excellent. I will write it as an answer then if you are able to accept it, would be great. Thanks

Comment: sure..please do it would really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your configuration as the error would indicate that you already have a listen directive to the same port.

`sudo vim /etc/apache2/ports.conf     [On Debian/Ubuntu]`

`sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf  [On RHEL/CentOS]`

Check that you don't have a listen on the port you need.

Comment: where can I find it

Answer (score 0):

In my case nginx server was running on the same PORT.
do the following:

1. `sudo service nginx stop`
2. `sudo systemctl restart apache2`
3. `sudo systemctl status apache2`  apache should have started.
4. to change nginx port: `cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` then `nano default` then search keyword `listen 80`, change this port no to other than 80.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Apache server not start | Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server
    
    I also faced same problem.
    
    First check
    
    sudo systemctl status nginx
    
    If nginx is active then stop this with
    
    sudo systemctl stop nginx

after that restart server
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run
```